# Are Terrapins sold in the UK?

Tags: reptiles, turtles, legal

I am from the UK and I was wondering if I can get terrapins. i have looked on all the websites of close by pet stores and none of them know where to get them from.

Comment: Look for pet shops dealing in exotic animals.

Comment: I made some minor wording changes to your question.  As originally written it was a shopping question which generally don't work well on StackExchange sites. The basic premise remains the same, but now it is a better fit for the site.  See [help asking](https://pets.stackexchange.com/help/asking) for more details

Comment: an other common name is red-eared slider so if you ask the petshops for this you might find it.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-eared_slider

Answer (score 3):

I have found out that there are many species which you can purchase legally in the UK, it was just the pet stores around where I live do not have them.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this breed is banned in the UK and EU, so there is no legal way to get this type of turtle in a pet shop, and it is not legal to breed red eared terrapins either: https://www.petgazette.biz/11350-red-eared-sliders-banned-uk/